# How do I hide Joins/Parts/Quits in Quassel IRC globally?

Tags: irc

I discovered that I can right click on any room's buffer and set the various things like Joins, Parts and Quits I want hidden.

But I want to set these defaults so that they are active on any room I go to. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just noticed that right underneath these options, there is an option saying 'Set as Default'... that worked across all rooms instantly :)